# how to resolve this error in Tesseract : (2, 'Usage: pytesseract [-l lang] input_file')

Tags: neural-network, image-recognition, ocr, colab, tesseract

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'/usr/local/bin/pytesseract'
img = Image.open("/content/drive/My Drive/abc.jpg")
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img))
```

stacktrace:

> --> print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img))
>
> sr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py in
>   image_to_string(image, lang, config, nice, output_type, timeout) 346
>   Output.DICT: lambda: {'text': run_and_get_output(*args)}, 347
>   Output.STRING: lambda: run_and_get_output(*args),
>   --> 348 }output_type 349 350
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py in
>   () 345 Output.BYTES: lambda: run_and_get_output(*(args + [True])), 346
>   Output.DICT: lambda: {'text': run_and_get_output(*args)},
>   --> 347 Output.STRING: lambda: run_and_get_output(*args), 348 }output_type 349
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py in
>   run_and_get_output(image, extension, lang, config, nice, timeout,
>   return_bytes) 256 } 257
>   --> 258 run_tesseract(**kwargs) 259 filename = kwargs['output_filename_base'] + extsep + extension 260 with
>   open(filename, 'rb') as output_file:
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py in
>   run_tesseract(input_filename, output_filename_base, extension, lang,
>   config, nice, timeout) 232 with timeout_manager(proc, timeout) as
>   error_string: 233 if proc.returncode:
>   --> 234 raise TesseractError(proc.returncode, get_errors(error_string)) 235 236
>
> TesseractError: (2, 'Usage: pytesseract [-l lang] input_file')

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54725151/pytesseract-tesseracterror-usage-python-pytesseract-py-l-lang-input-file

Comment: @Peter the solution provided over the link that you shred  is not working still getting same error.

Comment: Nevertheless, your question should be posted on SO.

Comment: @peter may i know what is SO ? why should it be posted there ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @peter this question  is also a part of datascience hence posted here.